# Comparando dados via Query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela chamada `Teste de aluno` e uma chamada `Parametros`
Necessito criar uma Query que compare se o teste está de acordo com os Parametros

O problema é que as tabelas não são 100% similares

Tabela Teste:

```
IDTESTE
PARAMETRO1
PARAMETRO2
PARAMETRO3
PARAMETRO4
PARAMETRO5
PARAMETRO6
PARAMETRO7
PARAMETRO8
PARAMETRO9
PARAMETRO10
IDANO
IDMATRICULA
IDALUNO
```

Tabela Parametro:

```
IDPARAMETRO
IDANO
PARAMETRO1
PARAMETRO2
PARAMETRO3
PARAMETRO4
PARAMETRO5
PARAMETRO6
PARAMETRO7
PARAMETRO8
PARAMETRO9
PARAMETRO10
```

Existe algum meio via Oracle de realizar essa comparação e verificar se os dados batem?

Dei uma pesquisada nos comandos `MINUS`, `INTERSECT` e `CASE`... mas achei meio nebuloso e como faria isso...

Comment: Como os dados se relacionam ? Creio que um simples JOIN resolva.

Comment: As duas tabelas não se relacionam entre si

Comment: Mas se as tabelas não guardam relação como compara-las , pensie em algo do tipo teste.IDTESTE = parametro.idIDPARAMETRO and teste.idano = parametro.idano , mas não parece ser isto.

Comment: Então, a tabela parâmetro literalmente so serve como parâmetro pra saber quais testes que validam os alunos

Comment: Não entendi, tente melhorar sua explicação inicial. Talvez com exemplos.

Comment: Você primeiro precisa saber com qual parâmetro da tabela parâmetros você quer comparar o seu teste. Pois na tabela parâmetros pelo nome dela, acho que ela pode guardar N registros de parâmetros diferentes. Ou uma alternativa seria você criar uma fk da tabela parametros dentro da tabela testeDeAluno, mas aí não teria sentido guardar os parametros na tabela testeDeAluno.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem a tua pergunta teria que ser algo assim:
O teste verifica se o valor das duas colunas forem iguais retorna 1, se forem diferentes retorna 0(Zero).
Assim tudo o que retornar "1" será verdadeiro.

**Utilizando decode:**
Decode seria com uma condição if mais que você consegue utilizar na query.

```
SELECT DECODE(tda.parametro1, p.parametro1, 1, 0) check_parametro1
      ,DECODE(tda.parametro2, p.parametro2, 1, 0) check_parametro1
  FROM teste_de_aluno tda
      ,parametros p
 WHERE p.id_parametro = 1
   AND tda.id_ano = p.id_ano;
```

**Utilizando case:**
Case também serve como uma condição if, mas voce pode fazer N testes um abaixo do outro utilizando o when (condicao);

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN tda.parametro1 = p.parametro1 THEN
          1
         ELSE
          0
       END check_parametro1
      ,CASE
         WHEN tda.parametro2 = p.parametro2 THEN
          1
         ELSE
          0
       END check_parametro2
  FROM teste_de_aluno tda
      ,parametros p
 WHERE p.id_parametro = 1
   AND tda.id_ano = p.id_ano;
```

Caso a tabela parametros guarde sempre apenas um registro, então nao precisa ter a restrição: *p.id_parametro = 1*, esta restrição serve para buscar na tabela parametros qual o registro entre todos que você deseja comparar com a tabela teste.